# Monolog and Symfony Class Loader

Tags: php, monolog

Monolog  : http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Symfony Class Loader : https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader

As per the usage instructions on the Monolog site, I'm trying to load the class loader to load monolog in my php project. I cant get 'Composer' installed on my machine (firewall problems from my work machine), so I'm trying to follow the instructions on monolog and symfony sites but I'm having issues.

Here is my SAMPLE of my directory structure with my php code :

```
myProj/
--ClassLoader/            (symfony)
----UniversalClassLoader.php
--Monolog/ 
----Formatter/
----Handler/
----Processor/
----Logger.php
--myPhpFile.php
```

And here is my php code to attempt to 'require' monolog

```
require_once(realpath('ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php'));   
$loader = new Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->register();
$loader->registerNamespace('Monolog', realpath('Monolog'));
require_once(realpath('Monolog\Logger.php'));    //exception generated here! :-(
```

and here is the php exception I'm getting inside the Monolog\Logger.php as soon as it attempts to 'require' monolog

```
Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found
```

but I cant even FIND anything that looks like a 'psr\log' namespace in the monolog code. What bits am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Psr\Log is a dependency of monolog, if you are not using Composer you'll have to track down all dependencies and it's probably not going to be fun (though for monolog there is only the psr-log package). If you really want you can find it at https://github.com/php-fig/log - but you could also try to download composer via your browser, just grab https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

Comment: eeeek! thanks for the answer. My experience of Composer is very limited, first time I've encountered it this morning, so perhaps I'll just try including the Psr\Log code from github.